# symlinks error due to permission in 16.04

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link, vagrant

I was trying to install a package using vagrant, this is the error I face:

```
Unable to create symlinks. Make sure you have permission to create symbolic links.
```

Vagrant uses `id:1000` from what I gathered.
`id` command gives the following output:

```
uid=1001(sachin) gid=1001(sachin) groups=1001(sachin),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

What should I do?